# web service testing tool for federated endpoints

Tags: testing, service, web, endpoints, federated

would anyone know of a WCF testing tool, much like soapui, that can be used to make calls to federated endpoints? If there is know such tool, any ideas on how to call these services would be appreciated. One idea i had was to create a basic http binding endpoint for every service but this would produce a lot of configuration overhead. Is this or creating my own tool to call the services the best approach?

Thanks,
Andy